Invalid block tag on line ...: 'endblock', expected 'endwith'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
I have a problem with my project on Python
Here is a code, that located in Django template
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% bootstrap_button button_type="submit" content="Отправить" %}
  </form>
  **{% with data=request.POST %}**
{% endblock %} 

When i reloading the page i receive an error on screenshot.
error screen
After the deleting this string, everything fine.
{% with data=request.POST %}
I dont understand what wrong ???
Iam trying to delete the string, that leads to an error, it helps, but according to the conditions of the task this string is must to be in this block of code

Looks like you forgot to include an {% endwith %} tag to close the {% with %} tag. The error message is say that the template engine was expecting to see a {% endiwth %} before an {% endblock %}, since you can't end and outer tag before and inner tag

You are missing the endwith tag.
You need to add it before your endblock content tag:
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}

{% block content %}

  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% bootstrap_button button_type="submit" content="Отправить" %}
  </form>
  {% with data=request.POST %}
{# do something with data variable #}
{% endwith %}

{% endblock %}


You need to add endwith, and use a valid syntax.
Try this :
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% bootstrap_button button_type="submit" content="Отправить" %}
  </form>
  **{% with data=request.POST %}**
  {% endwith %} 
{% endblock %} 


You have syntax errors
You need to add endwith tag
Try this:
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% bootstrap_button button_type="submit" content="Отправить" %}
  </form>
  **{% with data=request.POST %}**
    {% endwith %} 
{% endblock %} 

